# Batch, How to filter this HTML text to set a bit of vars

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed, grep, wget

i'm in a big problem

I use wget to send a post petition to a web, then i receive a html
And i need to filter this sample of the html:

```
more code up...

        <div id="song_html" class="show1">
            <div class="left">
            <!-- info mp3 here -->
                256 kbps<br />3:21<br />6.13 mb         </div>
            <div id="right_song">
                <div style="font-size:15px;"><b>Marilyn Manson - Tainted Love ( Manson Remix) mp3</b></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <div style="float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;">
                        <div style="float:left;"><a href="http://rockass.free.fr/video/Marilyn Manson - Taited Love.mp3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">Download</a></div> 
                                                <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left; width:27px; text-align:center;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showPlayer_new(37119, '91da6888c92ccb4198dbc78cb30f311635751694', 'marilyn+manson', 'tainted+love')" rel="nofollow" id="lk37119" class="play_now">Play</a></div>                     
                                                                        <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showEmbed_new(37119, '91da6888c92ccb4198dbc78cb30f311635751694')" rel="nofollow" id="em37119" class="embed">Embed</a></div>
                                                <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left;"><a href="http://www.ringtonematcher.com/go/?sid=WDLL&artist=marilyn+manson&song=tainted+love" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:red;" title="Send Marilyn Manson - Tainted Love Ringtone to your Cell">Descarga Tono</a></div> 
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="player37119" style="float:left; margin-left:10px;" class="player"></div>
                </div>  
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="song_html" class="show2">
            <div class="left">
            <!-- info mp3 here -->
                            </div>
            <div id="right_song">
                <div style="font-size:15px;"><b>Spaz Marilyn Manson Metric - grow up and blow the great big dj://spaz, marilyn manson  mp3</b></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <div style="float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;">
                        <div style="float:left;"><a href="http://spaz.mindstab.net/djspaz_-_grow_up_and_blow_the_great_big_white_nietzche.mp3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">Download</a></div> 
                                                <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left; width:27px; text-align:center;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showPlayer_new(668416, 'ac5b8834fa26b892fc1436db4678aca9d8acfdb1', 'spaz+marilyn+manson+metric', 'grow+up+and+blow+the+great+big+dj%3a%2f%2fspaz%2c+marilyn+manson')" rel="nofollow" id="lk668416" class="play_now">Play</a></div>                       
                                                                        <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showEmbed_new(668416, 'ac5b8834fa26b892fc1436db4678aca9d8acfdb1')" rel="nofollow" id="em668416" class="embed">Embed</a></div>
                                                <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left;"><a href="http://www.ringtonematcher.com/go/?sid=WDLL&artist=spaz+marilyn+manson+metric&song=grow+up+and+blow+the+great+big+dj%3a%2f%2fspaz%2c+marilyn+manson" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:red;" title="Send Spaz Marilyn Manson Metric - Grow Up And Blow The Great Big Dj://spaz, Marilyn Manson Ringtone to your Cell">Descarga Tono</a></div> 
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="player668416" style="float:left; margin-left:10px;" class="player"></div>
                </div>  
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>

    <div id="morelink" style="margin:10px; text-align:center;"><a href="" rel="nofollow" onClick="toggle(); return false;">Show More Results</a></div>


                <div id="song_html" class="show3">
            <div class="left">
            <!-- info mp3 here -->
                 3:10<br />         </div>
            <div id="right_song">
                <div style="font-size:15px;"><b>Marilyn Manson - MARILYN MANSON - Rock is Dead  mp3</b></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <div style="float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;">
                        <div style="float:left;"><a href="http://www.bricbrac.free.fr/Music/01___MARILYN_MANSON___ROCK_.MP3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">Download</a></div> 
                                                <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left; width:27px; text-align:center;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showPlayer_new(670124, '14a52b596082676bed6a9d860c383488a486e1dc', 'marilyn+manson', '-+rock+is+dead')" rel="nofollow" id="lk670124" class="play_now">Play</a></div>                     
                                                                        <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showEmbed_new(670124, '14a52b596082676bed6a9d860c383488a486e1dc')" rel="nofollow" id="em670124" class="embed">Embed</a></div>
                                                <div style="margin-left:8px; float:left;"><a href="http://www.ringtonematcher.com/go/?sid=WDLL&artist=marilyn+manson&song=-+rock+is+dead" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:red;" title="Send Marilyn Manson - - Rock Is Dead Ringtone to your Cell">Descarga Tono</a></div> 
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="player670124" style="float:left; margin-left:10px;" class="player"></div>
                </div>  
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>

</div>
</div>
<!-- ================= -->  

more code down...
```

...To set a bit of variables like "Name" "Bitrate" "Size" and "Download", To print all this information in Batch, like this:

```
1st result:
[Name]      Marilyn Manson - Tainted Love ( Manson Remix) mp3
[Info]      Bitrate: 256 kbps. Length: 3:21. Size: 6.13 mb.
[Download]  http://rockass.free.fr/video/Marilyn Manson - Taited Love.mp3

2nd result:
[Name]      Spaz Marilyn Manson Metric - grow up and blow the great big dj://spaz, marilyn manson  mp3
[Info]      NO INFO.
[Download]  http://spaz.mindstab.net/djspaz_-_grow_up_and_blow_the_great_big_white_nietzche.mp3

3rd result:
[Name]      Marilyn Manson - MARILYN MANSON - Rock is Dead  mp3
[Info]      Lenght: 3:10.
[Download]  http://www.bricbrac.free.fr/Music/01___MARILYN_MANSON___ROCK_.MP3
```

I've tryed "Findstr","Find","SED","GREP","FART" but i can't find the way (A line and chars delimitators) to do it right...

The only i can see to make it possible is this line:

```
<!-- ================= -->
```

I can use it like a END-delimitator cause that line marks the end of mp3's to download and to print their info...

Somebody can help me?

thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Batch file below use the fact that the data you want is located at fixed number of lines below "info mp3 here" line. Also, the data is extracted based on its position in the line. If some data not follow this rule, the program will need a modification.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
findstr /N /C:"info mp3 here" %1 > "%~N1.tmp"
set lastLine=-1
(for /F "usebackq delims=:" %%a in ("%~N1.tmp") do (
   set /A skip=%%a-lastLine
   for /L %%i in (1,1,!skip!) do set /P info=
   set /P =& set /P name=
   for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do set /P download=
   set "name=!name:*<b>=!
   for /F "delims=<" %%n in ("!name!") do echo [Name]      %%n
   set "info=!info:<br />= !"
   set "info=!info:</div>=!"
   set bitrate=
   set lenght=
   set size=
   set value=
   for %%t in (!info!) do (
      if not defined value (
         set value=%%t
      ) else ( 
         if %%t equ kbps (
            set "bitrate=Bitrate: !value! kbps. "
            set value=
         ) else if %%t equ mb (
            set "size=Size: !value! mb."
            set value=
         ) else (
            set "lenght=Lenght: !value!. "
            set value=%%t
         )
      )
   )
   if defined value (
      set "lenght=Lenght: !value!. "
   )
   set info=!bitrate!!lenght!!size!
   if not defined info set info=NO INFO.
   echo [Info]      !info!
   set "download=!download:"=$!"
   for /F "tokens=4 delims=$" %%d in ("!download!") do echo [Download]  %%d
   set /A lastline=%%a+6
)) < %1
del "%~N1.tmp"
```

Output:

```
[Name]      Marilyn Manson - Tainted Love ( Manson Remix) mp3
[Info]      Bitrate: 256 kbps. Lenght: 3:21. Size: 6.13 mb.
[Download]  http://rockass.free.fr/video/Marilyn Manson - Taited Love.mp3

[Name]      Spaz Marilyn Manson Metric - grow up and blow the great big dj://spaz, marilyn manson  mp3
[Info]      NO INFO.
[Download]  http://spaz.mindstab.net/djspaz_-_grow_up_and_blow_the_great_big_white_nietzche.mp3

[Name]      Marilyn Manson - MARILYN MANSON - Rock is Dead  mp3
[Info]      Lenght: 3:10.
[Download]  http://www.bricbrac.free.fr/Music/01___MARILYN_MANSON___ROCK_.MP3
```

Comment: Thankyou!. Can you tell me how much lines i need to "cut" at the begin of the sample html that i've posted? I get a fail output if I try to use your code with the sample html. Thanks again. I mean, The first line of the document need to be...which?

Comment: I think my program should run with any input file; the output I posted used your sample file above. Type this: `findstr /N /C:"info mp3 here" thefile.html` and check that the numbers correspond to the "mp3 info here" lines. If you still have problems, cut until a few lines above the first "mp3 info here" line. Remember that if some data have not the format I assumed, my program will fail as explained above.

Comment: i was tryed the other day "yourcode.bat file.html" and like i said i get a failed output, but now i've tryed again and all is ok, i don't know why...maybe i saved the first bat in utf or unicode format by error, now in ansi. Thankyou again!!!

Comment: ok was my fault, the bat only works if the html document have indentation lines like the sample html. unfortunately wget makes a html build in ONE line (My text editor recognizes the indentation of lines, But not the bat code)  bye!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script that will parse the information you want.

**The script takes the name of your HTML file as an argument**.

Output is sent to a file with name derived by appending '.parsed' to the input file name.

Comments at the top of the script give a little explanation of the patterns being used to locate the requested information in the HTML file.

**Replace the two instances of 'TAB' with tab characters and be sure that you retain the single space before each tab.**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Parse HTML with sed, suppressing all unwanted lines
  # "Info" lines all start with a number (ignoring whitespace)
  # Bitrate and file size can be identified by looking for
  #   the unit (kbps, mb) immediately following the numeric data
  # Length is identified by the colon in the middle of numeric data
  # File names are delimited by <b> and </b>
  # Lines with the URL all contain Download</a>
  # The </a> isn't necessary, but I thought it would be safer to
  #   include it since one could imagine "Download" appearing in a file name
# Pipe output to Awk for reordering of the parsed lines
#   and addition of "NO INFO" lines where necessary

sed -n '
/^[ TAB]*[0-9]/ {
  s/^[ TAB]*/[Info]      /
  s/\([0-9]*:[0-9]*\)[^0-9]*/Length: \1. /
  s/\([0-9\.]* .bps\)[^0-9L]*/Bitrate: \1. /
  s/\([0-9\.]* .b\)[^p][^0-9LB]*/Size: \1. /
  p
}
/<b>/ {
  s|</b>.*||
  s|.*<b>\(.*\)|[Name]      \1|
  p
}
\|Download</a>| {
  s/^.*\(http:[^"]*\).*/[Download]  \1/
  p
}' $1 | awk 'BEGIN { no_info = "[INFO]      NO INFO.";
                     info = no_info }
             { if ($1 == "[Name]") name = $0;
                 else if ($1 == "[Info]") info = $0;
                 else {
                   printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n\n", name, info, $0);
                   info = no_info
                 } }' > $1.parsed
exit 0
```

Comment: Hi, i appreciate so much your help...but that code is for linux.. i said i need to do it in batch , The title says Batch, And i mean i've tryed SED (And GREP) for Windows. Sorry if you was confused by that. I don't know how to ""convert"" that linux terms to do it right in batch bat, but thankyou again. I will investigate your code... bye

Comment: Sorry about that.  I totally spaced on the batch part.  Unfortunately, I don't speak Batch.  Maybe someone who can translate will come along.  I'd downvote myself, but apparently that's not an option.

Answer (score 1):

TXR 65 (Runs on Windows; MinGW-compiled .exe available)

```
@(collect)
 <div id="song_html" class="show@nil">
            <div class="left">
            <!-- info mp3 here -->
@(gather :vars ((bitrate nil) (length nil) (size nil)))
 @bitrate kbps@(skip)
@(skip)@{length /\d+:\d\d/}@(skip)
@(skip)@{size /\d+\.\d\d/} mb@(skip)
@(until)
            <div id="right_song">
@(end)
@(bind info @(if (or bitrate length size)
               (let ((s (make-string-output-stream)))
                 (if bitrate
                   (format s "Bitrate: ~a kbps. " bitrate))
                 (if length
                   (format s "Length: ~a. " length))
                 (if size
                   (format s "Size: ~a mb. " size))
                 (get-string-from-stream s))
               "NO INFO."))
            <div id="right_song">
                <div style="font-size:15px;"><b>@title</b></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <div style="float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;">
                        <div style="float:left;"><a href="@link" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">Download</a></div> 
@(until)
<!-- ================= -->  
@(end)
@(output)
@  (repeat)
[Name]      @title
[Info]      @info
[Download]  @link
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr data.txr data.html
[Name]      Marilyn Manson - Tainted Love ( Manson Remix) mp3
[Info]      Bitrate: 256 kbps. Length: 3:21. Size: 6.13 mb. 
[Download]  http://rockass.free.fr/video/Marilyn Manson - Taited Love.mp3
[Name]      Spaz Marilyn Manson Metric - grow up and blow the great big dj://spaz, marilyn manson  mp3
[Info]      NO INFO.
[Download]  http://spaz.mindstab.net/djspaz_-_grow_up_and_blow_the_great_big_white_nietzche.mp3
[Name]      Marilyn Manson - MARILYN MANSON - Rock is Dead  mp3
[Info]      Length: 3:10. 
[Download]  http://www.bricbrac.free.fr/Music/01___MARILYN_MANSON___ROCK_.MP3
```

Comment: Hi Kaz thanks, I will try your code but i don't understand the important part to use it on WIN. I've downloaded txr65.zip from your web but I can't find any executable inside, maybe you mean i need to intall TXR on linux, and then compile it with...with what? With MingW (On linux?)? Can you resolve my noob question please?